# How to achieve permutation and combination

Tags: r

I am a newbie in R. Now I have three vectors：T(0.6,0.65,0.70.75,0.8); Ho(0.025,0.032,0.038,0.045,0.05);HLen(1.5,2,3,4.5). I want to arrange and combine the elements of these three vectors, take an array of each vector and make a group of Numbers, and put each group of Numbers into a matrix. In the final matrix, I can see the situation of each combination. Can you implement such a function of the program？

Comment: have a look at [expand.grid](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/expand.grid)

Comment: `data <- expand.grid(vec1, vec2, vec3)`